# How can I separate data to new sheet in same excel file

Tags: javascript, csv, object, export-to-excel

If I have data within array2D and I want to separate each Device to each sheet in excel file. From my code below here where's the line do I have to change about exportToCSV() to solve this problem.

```
const rows = [
  ["DeviceA"]
  ["Date/Time", "smokeSensor", "fireSensor"],
  ["190501 00:01", "200", "700"],
  ["190501 00:02", "300", "750"],
  ["190502 00:01", "20", "780"],
  ["190502 00:02", "30", "630"],
  [""],
  ["DeviceB"],
  ["Date/Time", "smokeSensor", "fireSensor"],
  ["190501 00:01", "100", "600"],
  ["190501 00:02", "110", "522"],
  ["190502 00:01", "120", ""],
  ["190502 00:02", "130", ""],
];

function exportToCSV(rows) {
      let csvContent = ""
      rows.forEach(function(rowArray) {
          let row = rowArray.join(",")
          csvContent += row + "\r\n"
      });
      var link = document.createElement("a")
      document.body.appendChild(link)
      // var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "text/csv"}); 
      var blob = new Blob([csvContent], {type: "xls/xlsx"})
      var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      link.setAttribute("href", url)
      link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv")
      link.click() /* Download the data file named "my_data.csv". */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV does not support the separation of the data in sheets.

I created a JavaScript library called [ExcellentExport](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport) to export tables or arrays to CSV or Excel.

The excel export has support for sheets:

```
ExcellentExport.convert({ anchor: this, filename: 'data_123.array', format: 'xlsx'}, [
    {name: 'Sheet Name Here 1', from: {array: yourArray1}},
    {name: 'Sheet 2', from: {array: yourArray2}},
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, Eventually I used another library called sheetJS to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For CSV parsing you can use [Papa Parse.](https://www.papaparse.com/)
You can parse CSV to JSON and do the things and again you can parse back from JSON to CSV